# Как отключить ctrl +alt+del в python?

Tags: python

```
elevate()
os.system('REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /f /v "DisableTaskMgr" /t REG_DWORD /d 1')
```

это едиствий код который я нашел, но при запуске ошибка

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Покажите ваш импорт

Comment: import elevate as elevate и import os

Comment: from elevate import elevate

Comment: Спасибо сработало. А как потом назад включить диспетчер задач?

Comment: Enable вместо Disable

Comment: Не работает, диспетчер все равно заблокирован

Comment: Поспешил, значение 1 смените на 0

Comment: os.system('REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /f /v "DisableTaskMgr" /t REG_DWORD /d 0')

Comment: Cпасибо! Работает